# How do I convert this glob to regular expression with additional constraint (using Java 7)?

Tags: java, regex, glob

I was using this glob in Java 7 to only return audio files sucessfully

```
*.{mp3,mp4,m4p,m4b,m4a,ogg,flac,wma}
```

but I also need to filter out any files file starting with **._**

There doesnt seem to be way to exclude patterns only, include with globs so I then switched to regular expressions but not having much luck, this is my current (no working attempt)

```
[^\.].*\.{mp3,mp4,m4a,ogg,flac,wma}
```

Could I have a solution using either glob or a regexp please

Comment: Are you filtering files starting with just `_`, or `._`?

Comment: Files that start with ._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out: -

```
^(?!._).*[.](?:mp3|mp4|m4p|m4b|m4a|ogg|flac|wma)$
```

**Explanation: -**

```
^      // Beginning of the string
(?!._) // Negative look-ahead to confirm that there is no `._` at the starting.

.*      // 0 or more any character

[.]     // A dot (.)

(?:mp3|mp4|m4p|m4b|m4a|ogg|flac|wma)  // Any one extension matched at the end.
$
```

Note that, you don't need to escape the `dot (.)` in a character class.

`(?:...)` is a *non-capturing* group.

Comment: Thankyou that helps alot, but wont that filter out songs starting with a underscore I only want to filter out songs that start with dot and then underscore

Comment: Thankyou I would never have got that last bit on my own.